# Isolated points and Baire category theorem

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, baire-category

Let $(X,d)$ be compact. Can the set of isolated points be countably infinite? Are the set of isolated points constitute a discrete set? Also I would like to know whether we can consider "the intersection point" in the proof of Baire Category theorem as an isolated points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ with the usual Euclidean metric that it inherits from $\Bbb R$; this is a compact metric space, and all of its points except $0$ are isolated, so it has countably infinitely many isolated points. A compact metric space cannot have **uncountably** many isolated points, however, because it is separable, and a dense subset of a space must contain every isolated point of that space.

I’m not sure what you mean by ‘the intersection point’ in the proof of the Baire Category Theorem, but none of the points that are constructed in the usual proof is necessarily isolated.

Comment: "the intersection points" means the point we get from cantor's intersection theorem. As it is exactly one point, i am referring as "the intersection point"

Comment: @Sakh10: One does not actually need the Cantor intersection theorem to prove the BCT for metric spaces, though that is certainly one way to prove it. No, there is no reason to think that that point is an isolated point, and in general it won’t be one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found one hint  "Any such set will be a closed subset of the compact space and hence complete". Can you please explain this hint to get the same conclusion of yours

Comment: @Sakh10: I would need more context; what does *any such set* here refer to?

Comment: Any such set means set of isolated points. This hint i got from a book. I couldn't understand it

Comment: @Sakh10: I don’t understand it either: a set of isolated points in a compact metric need not be closed, as you can see from the example in my answer.

Comment: But all the singletone set will be closed, hence the union of closed sets will be closed.

Comment: @Sakh10: The union of **finitely many** closed sets is always closed, but the union of **infinitely many** closed sets need not be.

Comment: Ok, I got it sir. I was thinking whether it is possible to use the Baire category theorem and the fact that the singleton sets will be closed. Then using the fact that X is complete (as it is given compact), Hence using BCT somehow conclude your result that it is possible to have countably infinite set of isolated points.